# Why sending content by intent does not work

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have an activity that contains many posts in a recyclerview and each post placed in a cardView (posts are getting from my database in my host). I wanted to use sending intent to share any of posts. My share button works but works in a wrong way.

For example when I click to share my first post, it shares the third post! and when I click to share the seventh post, it shares the tenth post and so on.

What wrong with it? anyone can help?

This is my xml:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/send_post"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:onClick="sharedtextClicked"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

and this is my share code :

```
public void sharedtextClicked(View view) {
    String txt=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Postcontent)).getText().toString();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,txt);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
}
```

and this is my adapter:

```
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_post,parent,false);
    Typeface arialTypeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/arial.ttf");
    return new PostviewHolder(view,arialTypeface);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PostviewHolder holder, int position) {

    Post post=posts.get(position);
    holder.content.setText(post.getContent());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return posts.size();
}

public class PostviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView content;

    public PostviewHolder(View itemView, Typeface arialTypeface) {
        super(itemView);
        content=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Postcontent);
        content.setTypeface(arialTypeface);
    }
}
```

this is layout_post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
app:cardElevation="2dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp">
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Postcontent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
         />
   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/send_post"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:onClick="sharedtextClicked"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimary" />
 </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you show your adapter code?

Comment: @MichaelMontero i put my adapter,check it out

Comment: show the code where you call `shareTextClicked` method.

Comment: @SonTruong I don't call it. it is the method for onClick feature that i used in xml file as you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you logic is not correct. Try this one

**Remove** `android:onClick="sharedtextClicked"` from *layout_post.xml* file

**Delete** `sharedtextClicked` method.

**Change** your code in adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostviewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.content.setText(post.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getContent());
    holder.sendPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, post.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getContent());
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            Context context = view.getRootView().getContext();
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, context.getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
        }
    });
}

public class PostviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView content;
        private ImageButton sendPost;

        public PostviewHolder(View itemView, Typeface arialTypeface) {
            super(itemView);
            content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Postcontent);
            sendPost = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.send_post);
            content.setTypeface(arialTypeface);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i did it but there was no change and also it didn't help for my problem

Comment: I got it. Can you share `layout_post.xml` file?